# Restarting a WiFi device after Windows 7 crash/freeze

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, freeze

My notebook freezes (trouble of cooling system, never mind). On Windows 7 (I previously used Vista), after unfreezing (frozen ~ 2-5 mins), the WiFi will crash. I have to re-enable the device to get it working.

How I can automate the re-enabling of the WiFi device after a system crash or freeze?

On Vista it worked fine after freezing.

Comment: Have you checked for new wi-fi drivers?

Answer (score 0):

How to reset the wifi device depends upon what wifi device it is and the manufacturer. Try updating the drivers first. After that, manually re-enable the wifi and then properly shutdown the computer. In my experience, Windows typically uses the last state you left the device in when it starts. YMMV.